# Implement a rust function that only accepts types that possess a certain method

Tags: rust, traits

I want to create a function that only accepts types that possess a certain method. For example, I know that the `f32` and `f64` primitive types possess a [`log10`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.log10) method, and I therefore want a function that only accepts these types. One way I thought of doing this was to implement a trait for `f32` and `f64` that contains a function that will itself call `log10`, e.g.,

```rust
trait Log10 {
    fn log10_t(&self) -> f64;
}

impl Log10 for f32 {
    fn log10_t(&self) -> f64 {
        self.log10() as f64
    }
}

impl Log10 for f64 {
    fn log10_t(&self) -> f64 {
        self.log10()
    }
}
```

I could then have a function that only accepts types that implement `Log10`, e.g.,

```rust
fn my_log10<T: Log10>(f: T) -> f64 {
    f.log10_t() as f64
}
```

This works, but I was wondering if there was a better/simpler way? For example, one that doesn't require me to implement my intermediate `log10_t` function. Or, one that can actually still keep the output as the type of the input value (my methods converts outputs to `f64` no matter the input type).

Comment: You can avoid the conversion to `f64` by having your `log10` method return `Self`, or by using an associated type (e.g. if you want each implementation to be able to choose the type freely).

Comment: At the very least, the function signature can be simplified: `fn my_log10(f: impl Log10) -> f64`

Answer (score 3):

Using a trait is the way to go. You can use a macro to reduce the boilerplate. Also note that there is no need to name the method `log10_t()`, you can name it just `log10()`.

In this specific case of numeric methods, you can use the [`num-traits`](https://docs.rs/num-traits) crate that defines traits for pretty much every numeric method in std. They also support non-std types, such as [`num-bigint`](https://docs.rs/num-bigint). For example, it defines [`Float`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/float/trait.Float.html) with [`log10()`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/float/trait.Float.html#tymethod.log10) method.

Comment: Thanks. If I try just naming it `log10` I get the compile error `warning: function cannot return without recursing`.

Comment: @MattPitkin yeah `self` is not sufficient to distinguish between the trait and the inherent method, and rustc defaults to the trait. You can fix the issue by using UFCS, and invoking `f64::log10(*self)`.

Comment: @MattPitkin This is because `self` is a reference, and the inherent method is on `f64`, not `&f64`, so rust defaults to the trait. You can fix that by dereferencing: `(*self).log10()` (or UFCS as @Masklinn suggested).